# What ways are there to make a hitbox in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, hittest, hit

How many ways are there to create a hit box?

I have a `Player` class, which has a sprite and I want an accurate hitbox for it.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Is there any reason why you need multiple ways of doing so?

Comment: You might want to look here ;) [AS3 hitboxes](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=199391)